# How to find elements on a JavaScript Website with Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation, webdriverwait

I want to automate some searching stuff for myself, but I have a bit of a problem here.
On this website:

> https://shop.orgatop.de/

The program can't find the search bar, and I don't really know why.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://shop.orgatop.de/')
input_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="solrSearchTerm"]')))
input_search.click()
input_search.send_keys('asd')
input_search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is present inside nested iframe like `innerFrame>catalog>content>input`.You need to switch those frame first inorder to access the input search box.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://shop.orgatop.de/')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"innerFrame")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"catalog")))
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"content")))
input_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="solrSearchTerm"]')))
input_search.click()
input_search.send_keys('asd')
input_search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

**Browser snashot:**

[image]

Comment: It give me an error:
 File "C:\Users\Aron\Desktop\apa\kereso2.py", line 28, in <module>                                                         WebDriverWait(driver,1
0).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME,"content")))
 File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until                                  raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: @Pilv : Try the updated answer now.Elements is present in a nested frames.Let me know how this goes.It worked with me.

Comment: Thanks! It works. If it's not much to ask for, can you please explain me why this works?

Comment: @Pilv : Just read my answer description.I have mentioned that the Input search box you are interacting it is inside nested frame elements.So selenium can't interact this kind of input directly until you switched those frames first.That is what I did in this code.Thanks.